# JSON Schema validate array filtering its elements

Tags: jsonschema, json-schema-validator, ajv

I'm trying to validate an array of objects property that contains at least 3 items that matches:

`x.foo == 'bar'`.

For example

```js
{
    ...
    array: [
        { id: 1, foo: 'bar'}, { id: 2, foo: 'bar' }, {id: 3, foo: 'bar'}, { id: 4, foo: 'not-bar'}
    ]
}
```

This matches because there are at least 3 items where foo == 'bar' is true.

In other words, I'm trying to figure out how to filter an array property and then validate its length with certain conditions.

Is there a standard way to do this using JSON schema?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the latest draft (2020-12) there is "minContains" keyword that you can use here, together with "contains" and "const":

```json
{
  "minContains": 3,
  "contains": {
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
      "foo": {
        "const": "bar"
      }
    }
  }
}
```